# Как сделать метод универсальным?

Tags: java, selenium, test-automation

Пишу метод упрощающий чтение кода и никак не могу сделать его так, что бы он был универсальный

```
public class Pages {

public void searchByText(String text) {

    $(byText(text));

}
```

}

```
pages.searchByText("Текст");
```

Но хочется сделать так, что бы можно было работать с методами самого selenide через свой метод

Т.Е. вот так > `pages.searchByText("Текст").shouldBe(visible);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уж совсем универсально делать, чтобы метод был один - то, что-то типа такого:

```
public SelenideElement SearchElement(SearchBy by, string value)
{
  switch (by)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Где SearchBy - енум со всем добром что вы хотите юзать в качестве поиска.

Ну и человек через intellisense сам выбирает что использовать для поиска и передаёт значение, а реализация конкретно в свитче уже.